# Cannot deploy React site on Azure. Single file not loaded

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I decided to try to deploy a React website on Azure. (From Azure Devops Pipeline). This site works perfectly on localhost, but when I push it to Azure app service I get this error:

I get error message:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Looking at the console I see that there is just one file that is not loaded. It is GLTF file that is 3d graphics file. (Loading without problems on my computer). Yet in Azure App it gives 404 -not found and I just get black screen.

This file is being pushed into the Repo. It is where it should be. And all other files are loading fine. So that is not the issue.

I am new to Azure and was wondering if someone has run into similar issue?